# Is buttermilk preferred for sourdough starter?

Tags: sourdough-starter

Is buttermilk a preferred milk for sour dough starter?

Comment: Welcome! You don't necessarily need milk at all for a sourdough starter. Can you add some more details about what you hope to do, or what you want to learn?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Milk instead of water for sourdough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36927/milk-instead-of-water-for-sourdough)

Comment: This is the first I've ever heard of it so, no, it is not preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Normal sourdough starter is usually just [flour and water](https://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/sourdough-starter-recipe). However, there are less common alternatives such as using [fruit yeast](https://blog.kingarthurflour.com/2016/09/24/wild-grape-sourdough-starter/) and other sources of yeast.

The main problem with using things like milk or buttermilk is the danger of causing spoilage.

As another [commenter](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36927/milk-instead-of-water-for-sourdough) already added,

> "Adding milk works because milk is mostly water. It might even work
>   better, as it also contains sugar (lactose) which will be eaten by
>   your starter's yeasts and bacteria.
>
> But it also contains other stuff, such as fats. And fats, after some
>   time, get rancid. You probably won't want that taste in bread or
>   pancakes. I would stick to water (which quite probably you'll find
>   cheaper than milk).
>
> Don't worry about rotten milk: your starter is already rotten. And
>   it's a hostile environment for most microbes. It's very very
>   improbable new microbes would survive there. But if they do, they'll
>   be quite similar to the already existing ones."

A great overview from this [comment](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/43028/starters-fruit-fermentation-vs-just-flour-starters):

> "A sourdough starter is just Flour + Water + Time
>
> Some add catalysts such as pineapple juice or grape skins etc. But
>   what is fermenting is the flour! and this is the starter.
>
> Once the starter is made, however you choose to make one, the finished
>   starter will be a flour + water. The added "catalysts" are just to
>   help make one. Once it is made then generally it is just fed flour +
>   water to be kept going indefinitely.
>
> There is such a thing as Yeast Water which is made and kept going with
>   fruit but that is different.
>
> When a starter is used in a sourdough it will be flour + water. The
>   temperature and feeding schedule will affect the starter either making
>   it more yeast or bacterial therefore making it more or less sour. But
>   what also effects the final bread is how the starter is used within
>   the dough, i.e. how much starter to use, how long the dough is
>   fermented and at what temperature.
>
> So many factors involved here.
>
> No two people have exactly the same starter. And one starter can bring
>   out different qualities in different breads depending on how it is
>   used. And a change in feeding can change your starter.
>
> Welcome to sourdough."

[Best practices](http://farmtotable.colostate.edu/prepare-ferment/sourdough.php#.XLFMLTBKiUk) from Colorado State University:

> "Considerations for bread starter variations: Amish Friendship Bread:
>   Although rare, there have been incidents of foodborne illness
>   associated with friendship-style bread, which differs from traditional
>   sourdough by addition of milk and sugar, and thus provides an
>   environment which could support growth of harmful microorganisms. To
>   limit introductions of harmful bacteria in friendship bread starter,
>   use pasteurized milk or cultured (soured) dairy and ferment in a
>   refrigerator, not at room temperature."

[Signs](https://living.thebump.com/can-sick-baking-bread-bad-starter-9205.html) your starter may have gone wrong:

> "Signs of Contamination A starter should be white, light gray or light
>   tan. It should smell like bread dough, of yeast or of its ingredients.
>   It should bubble subtly and occasionally burp. If the starter has
>   liquid on top of it -- this is called hooch, and it is the alcohol the
>   starter’s yeast produces from fermentation -- it should be clear,
>   white, light gray or light brown. If the starter or its hooch is pink,
>   green or dark brown, discard the starter. If it smells or looks moldy,
>   discard the starter. If the starter is fizzing or the starter has
>   spots or patches -- which are signs of foreign bacterial growth --
>   discard the starter."